# Maximum two-dimensional subset-sum

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, subset, subset-sum

I'm given a task to write an algorithm to compute the maximum two dimensional subset, of a matrix of integers. - However I'm not interested in help for such an algorithm, I'm more interested in knowing the complexity for the best worse-case that can possibly solve this.

Our current algorithm is like O(n^3).

I've been considering, something alike divide and conquer, by splitting the matrix into a number of sub-matrices, simply by adding up the elements within the matrices; and thereby limiting the number of matrices one have to consider in order to find an approximate solution.

Comment: That would be the matrix itself, right? ;)

Comment: What? - Not sure I get what your saying, really wouldn't it depend on wether theres negatives numbers in the matrix?

Comment: Ahh good point.  You did say integers not non-negative integers. ;)  So you're looking for a sub-rectangle of numbers within your matrix such that the sum of the numbers in that rectangle is the maximum of that of all possible rectangles?

Comment: Yes indeed, or morelikely I'm looking for the complexity of the best algorithm for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured that there isn't a better way to do it. - At least not known to man yet.
And I'm going to stick with the solution I got, mainly because its simple.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case (exhaustive search) is definitely no *worse* than O(n^3).  There are several descriptions of this on the web.

Best case can be far better: O(1).  If all of the elements are non-negative, then the answer is the matrix itself.  If the elements are non-positive, the answer is the element that has its value closest to zero.

Likewise if there are entire rows/columns on the edges of your matrix that are nothing but non-positive integers, you can chop these off in your search.